# Filtering elements by data= attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a case where I need to filter by elements and by all means; almost works.

There is a list of colors the user could chose from. More than one color can be selected. Each element can have one or more of these attributes assigned to it.

**Attribute Example:**

```
<div data-wotc-color="G">
<div data-wotc-color="B">
<div data-wotc-color="U">
<div data-wotc-color="UB">
<div data-wotc-color="U">
<div data-wotc-color="W">
```

**In JQuery I'm doing this to show/hide by using filter():**

```
$.each($('.colorpicker a'), function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $('.pac').filter('[data-wotc-color*="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').show();
        } else {
            $('.pac').filter('[data-wotc-color*="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').hide();
        }
    });
```

Basically what's happening (as far as I can see) is when you select one element it works to show/hide the element. When selecting more than one it shows/hides properly as long as you select it in the proper order. I know some sort of regex is probably needed here but I'm not entirely sure how to make it happen using JQuery.

Comment: And what is your problem? Please provide a http://jsfiddle.net demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that for ***each*** anchor you're ***hiding*** some of the elements that may have already been (legitimately) showing.

Instead, hide everything, and then show the ones for selected colors:

```
// Hide EVERYTHING
$('.pac').hide();

// Now show everything that matches:
$('.colorpicker a.selected').each(function() {
    $('.pac').filter('[data-wotc-color*="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').show();
});
```

Comment: I knew it was going to be a simple fix and thanks for pointing out the a.selected in the $.each as well. Nice to cut a line out :)